# How can I write in EditText at any position?

Tags: android, xml

If I click in center into EditText my cursor will be move to start position but I want edit my Edit Text in any position wherever I click, for example - center. How can I do it?

My code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/description_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="Name" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any position ? It is not possible. Maybe if you "fill" your `EditText` with space character...

If you want to enter character from the middle, use `android:gravity="top|center"`

Comment: Could you give an example of how to fill EditText completely with spaces?

Comment: Sure. In your code `myEditText.setText("            ")` Put any spaces you want

Answer (score 0):

If your edittext is filled with content, you may click any character and the cursor will move to where you click.